# Has any FIFA World Cup winner ever had all their knockout stage matches won in extra time/penalties?

Tags: football, world-cup

Croatia is going into the World Cup finals having won their 3 knockout matches so far in extra time/penalties. If they bring their match against France to extra time and win, they'll have done it in every single knockout stage match.

Has any team ever won a World Cup by winning all of their knockout matches on extra time/penalties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***No*** team has ever won a World Cup by winning all of their knockout matches on extra time/penalties and [Croatia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Croatia_national_football_team) will be the first team to do so if they manage to do it.

Referencing to my answer on this question, "[Most extra time games played in a World Cup](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/18844/13485)", most number of games a team has played extra time (consecutive or otherwise) in a single World Cup is 3 times. So, Croatia will be the first team to play **four** extra time games even if they don't win it.

References used in [my linked answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/18844/13485):

1. [FIFA World Cup™ extra time matches (contains record for matches up-to 2006 world cup)](http://www.fifa.com/mm/document/fifafacts/mcwc/ip-201_15a_fwc_aet_pso_new_8859.pdf)
2. [2010 FIFA World Cup results](https://www.fifa.com/worldcup/archive/southafrica2010/matches/index.html)
3. [2014 FIFA World Cup results](https://www.fifa.com/worldcup/archive/brazil2014/matches/index.html)
4. [Live Match-blog England vs Croatia FIFA official site](https://www.fifa.com/worldcup/matches/match/300331522/#match-liveblog)